# Default Constructor Recursion Crash

Tags: c++

/*The following program seems to mysteriously enter recursion even though there is none in sight. 
Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Machine: x86 
OS: Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit

*/

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Test
    {
    public:
      Test ():x(9)
      {
        cout << " Test::Test\n";
        Test (x);
      }
      Test (int a)
      {
        cout << " Test::para\n";
      }
    private:
            int x;
    };


int main(void)
{
 Test a;
return 0;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: If i change x to some hard-coded value say any Int , its working fine , else it calls default constructor again n again,,

Comment: Why are you calling the parameterized constructor inside the default constructor?? x is already initialized using the member initializer there. BTW you could also define `Test(int a = 9)` and omit the default constructor at all.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In 2012 at such a fundamental place? seriously?

Comment: @PlasmaHH well, we were never told which compiler this is about... For all we know it could be a compiler from the last century. It wouldn't be the first time here on SO.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: MSVC and gcc-4.3.4 both show the same behavior.

Comment: same strange behaviour with clang++ (Debian clang version 3.0-6, x86_64)

Answer (score 9):

```
Test (x);
```

is parsed as

```
Test x;
```

... not as a constructor call.
You can also write

```
Test (y);
```

and get the same behaviour.

Comment: The old "if it could be a declaration or a statement-expression, it's a declaration" strikes again!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call other constructors like that in C++. But starting with C++11, you can forward constructor calls in the initialiser list:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test (): Test(9) {
        cout << " Test::Test\n";
    }

    Test (int a) : x(a) {
        cout << " Test::para\n";
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

See [Wolfgang’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814418/1968) for an explanation of why your code crashes.